# Using format validator for number range

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am working with regular expressions. This is a simple example. I want the user to be able to enter numbers only between 1 and 31, like this: ([1-31]), but I don't know why it doesn't accept numbers greater than 10:

[image]

Comment: You should really read some tutorials on regex, in such a short example you're showing a lack of even basic regex knowledge.  Try http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: A regex [class] works with *characters* not numeric ranges, 1-31 matches the character range 1 to 3 (or 1). You could; `^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])$`

Comment: but why here work ^(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((0[1-9])|([1-31]))\/((19|20)\d\d)$ this is an example (format of date )

Comment: That one has 1-31 as well which looks like an error to me.

Comment: Why not use a [Range Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator(v=vs.110).aspx)? They are designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: my objectif is expression validator i know i can do that with Range Validator but i can't make for example  format of date  this was my first short example for learning more and to understand other  difficult examples thank you so mush !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
^[0-3]?[0-9]$
```

More examples for matching numeric ranges and explanations behind them here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: This fails (meaning allows it when it shouldn't) for 0, 00, and 32-39.

Comment: Well sure, it "works" but something like `^([12]\d|[1-9]|3[01])$` would be more accurate.

Comment: Also Mr Daniel Cook  your Expression is correct but i am a biginner for that so i find the first answer by Moo very easy to understand  than your answer  in all cases thank you so mush !! And Moo !!

Comment: this is what i want finally :D thanks for help !!  ^(([0-2]?[1-9]|[3][0]|[3][1])/(([0-1]?[1-2])|([1][0])|([0]?[1-9]))/(\d{4}))$ (dd/MM/yyyy)

Answer (score -2):

Hi please check your syntax!this code in below accepts number between 6 to 20:

```
<asp:RegularexpressionValidator
 ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,20}" />
```

Comment: This accepts letters and is restricted by length not value as the OP requires

Comment: this is false is a bad answer sorry

Comment: -1 I think you misunderstood the question... your regex will allow between 6 and 20 alphanumeric characters... it will not validate against a numeric value between 1 and 31.